# pytest: how to get return value from a fixture and pytest.mark.parametrize in the same function

Tags: pytest, fixtures

I am trying to accomplish the following:

- pytest fixture returns the db handle
- pytest.mark.parametrize passes the arguments against which the test will be run

I went through pytest docs, multiple forums. I did not get any answer. Can someone suggest a solution for the problem? or an alternate way of doing this?

**EDIT 1:**
I want the db connections to happen only once in setup function. This db connection is used in all test function. Test function will be run against parameters from the parametrize values. How do I return the db_conn value from fixture?

```py
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def conn():
    db_conn = get_db_conn()
    yield db_conn
    db_conn.close()


@pytest.mark.parametrize("arg",[1,2,3])
def test_1(arg):
    db_conn.insert(arg)
    process(arg)

@pytest.mark.parametrize("arg",["a","b","c"])
def test_2(arg):
    db_conn.insert(arg)
    process(arg)
```

Comment: `def test_1(arg)` -> `def test_1(conn, arg)`. `pytest` will look for a fixture for every argument in test signature that is not explicitly parametrized. (there are some edge cases like keyword args or `mock.patch` returns, but they are not relevant in your case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have tried passing `conn` fixture as an argument for tests?

```py
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def conn():
    db_conn = get_db_conn()
    yield db_conn
    db_conn.close()


@pytest.mark.parametrize("arg",[1,2,3])
def test_1(arg, conn):
    conn.insert(arg)
    process(arg)

@pytest.mark.parametrize("arg",["a","b","c"])
def test_2(arg, conn):
    conn.insert(arg)
    process(arg)
```

This simple mock (`test_fixture_params.py`) should demonstrate the usage:

```py
import pytest


@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def conn():
    print('Opening db connection')
    yield 'MY DB CONNECTION'
    print('Closing db connection')


@pytest.mark.parametrize("arg",[1,2,3])
def test_1(arg, conn):
    print(conn, arg)


@pytest.mark.parametrize("arg",["a","b","c"])
def test_2(arg, conn):
    print(conn, arg)
```

For `pytest -s test_fixture_params.py` the output should be:

```
$ pytest -s test_fixture_params.py 
===================================================== test session starts =====================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.8.1, pytest-5.4.3, py-1.8.1, pluggy-0.13.1
collected 6 items                                                                                                             

test_fixture_params.py Opening db connection
MY DB CONNECTION 1
.MY DB CONNECTION 2
.MY DB CONNECTION 3
.MY DB CONNECTION a
.MY DB CONNECTION b
.MY DB CONNECTION c
.Closing db connection


====================================================== 6 passed in 0.03s ======================================================
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like yield-fixtures are deprecated. I resolved my case with this.
(the try/except block is in case the test method is not so naive true/false and could raise bad thingys :)

**Long story short: yes, pass fixture by name and use additional "request" param and its .getfixturevalue method**

```
import pytest

class TestFoo:
    @pytest.fixture
    def odd_numbers(self):
        return [1, 3, 5, 7]

    @pytest.fixture
    def even_numbers(self):
        return [2, 4, 6, 8]

    @pytest.fixture
    def mixed_numbers(self):
        return [1, 2, 3, 4]

    @pytest.mark.parametrize(
        ("fixture_name", "expected"),
        [
            pytest.param("mixed_numbers", True, marks=pytest.mark.xfail),
            pytest.param("odd_numbers", False),
            pytest.param("even_numbers", True),
        ],
    )
    def test_is_even_number(self, fixture_name, expected, request):
        numbers = request.getfixturevalue(fixture_name)
        result = expected
        for number in numbers:
            try:
                result = number % 2 == 0
            except:
                result = False
            assert result == expected
```